# server is not storing view state as the value of javax.faces.ViewState post migration to wildfly 10 from JBoss 6

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, wildfly

We have migrated our application from JBoss 6 to Wildfly 10. After migration the server is not storing the view state as the value of javax.faces.ViewState hidden input field after the first http response.

Application logic is storing it on server end and the scenario is to validate input text field on click of submit button. After the first http response the hidden input field disappears and on submitting some text value again, the text value is deleted and bean.xml is not called.

There has been no change in the application end. However the only difference is: Jboss had web.xml deployed with servlet mapping provided in the application war and in case of wildfly user has to deploy the war of application with wildfly 10 independently installed on the machine.

Primefaces 3.4, JSF 2.2 and Mojarra 2.2.14 is used.
The modules.xml is as below:

Path: \modules\system\layers\base\com\sun\jsf-impl\main

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.sun.jsf-impl">
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xerces" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xalan" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.weld.core"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.weld.spi"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.rpc.api"/>
    <module name="javax.rmi.api"/>
    <module name="org.omg.api"/>
</dependencies>

<resources>
    <resource-root path="jsf-impl-2.2.14.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Path: \modules\system\layers\base\javax\faces\api\main

```
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="javax.faces.api" slot="2.2.14">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.glassfish.javax.el" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
<resources>
        <resource-root path="jsf-api-2.2.14.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

What is being missed here?